# Sum up all matching elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays

How can I sum up all of the matching elements in an array? I currently trying to use a nested for loop, but if a number occurs more than 2 times it won't sum up the total correctly.I feel like am missing something small here.

```
public class Game {
ColoredDice dice[] = new ColoredDice[6];
private int diceValues[] = new int[6];

public Game() {
    rollSixDice();  
    score();
}

public void rollSixDice(){
    for(int i = 0;i < 6;i++){
        dice[i] = new ColoredDice();
    }
    // getDiceValue returns the int value of the die
    for(int i =0;i<dice.length;i++){
        diceValues[i] = dice[i].getDiceValue();
    }
}

public void score(){
    for(int i=0;i<dice.length;i++){
        for(int j = i+1 ;j < 6;j++){
            if(dice[i].getDiceValue() == diceValues[j]){
                score += dice[i].getDiceValue();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(score);
  } 
}


public class DiceTester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
new Game();
  }
}
```

To be clear more then what on what happens..
Both arrays here are identical and are of type int.
Example role values: 2,3,4,2,6,6.
Score:8

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
for(int i=0;i < dice.length;i++){
        for(int j =i+1;j < dice.length;j++){
            if(dice[i].getDiceValue() == dice[j].getDiceValue()){
                score += dice[i].getDiceValue();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: While I understand that you wish to be helpful, please try to avoid answering questions that do not meet the quality standards set out in the [help].

Comment: Sure, i will make a note of it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use hash map where key is on which you want do group and value is sum.This will increase space complexity to O(N) and time complexity O(N).
Or you can do O(nlogn) by sorting first and then summing the same element consecutively